# ":input" does not select disabled inputs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the `$(':input')` selector but it's not selecting disabled ones, nor hidden ones.

```
$(':input').serialize()
```

Although the form tag is enclosing everything, it just serialize a few ones because other parts are in other divs and that seems to broke the form.

Is there anyway to select all inputs including hidden and disabled ones?

I know I could do it by selecting manually by each field's ID but it's not the best approach IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the `:input` selector isn't targeting disabled inputs, it's that the `serialize()` method does not serialize disabled inputs.

The [`serialize()` documentation states](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/);

> Note: Only ["successful controls"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) are serialized to the string.

The link goes on to explain that; **Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.**.

Hidden input fields should be both selected by the `:input` selector, and serialized by the `serialize()` method; which is what this JSFiddle shows; http://jsfiddle.net/H2g6Q/

Comment: And how could I serialize them?

Comment: @AntonioLaguna: You'd have to un-disable them, serialize the elements, and then re-disable them.

Comment: I made the trick and it works with ''var disabled = $(':disabled');
            disabled.attr('disabled', false);
            var data = $(':input').serialize();
            disabled.attr('disabled', true);''

Comment: BTW, if you want to submit those fields, then they shouldn't be disabled in the first place. Have a look at the `readonly` attribute instead.

Comment: That's a really great comment, I didn't knew about that attr